# Проблема с позиционированием в css column layout

Tags: css3, layout, position

Есть простой набор `inline-block` дивов, которые располагаются с использованием **`css column layout`**.

Возникает жуткая проблема. **Дочерние элементы** дивов, расположенных во всех колонках, начиная со второй **исчезают** при следующих условиях:

- У дива задано свойство `overflow: hidden`.
- У дочерних элементов установлено свойство `position` любое, кроме `static`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти два условия являются взаимоисключающими.

Подскажите, что я упускаю? Даже не знаю какой раздел спецификации листать.

В некоторых браузерах работает. Но не в chrome for desktop, chrome for android.

### [Демо на codepen](http://codepen.io/light-flight/pen/LZEYeN?editors=0100)

Comment: Боюсь что листание спеки не поможет, вам скорее багтрекер хрома листать надо. А вообще заходим на http://caniuse.com, ищем используемую вами фичу: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn, по ходу офигеваем от того сколь мало она поддерживается, жмем на таб "resources" и там есть ссылочка на спеку

Comment: Вы правы. Самое интересное, что даже в самых левых браузерах работает. Например у меня на телевизоре :D

Comment: Багтрекер хромиума вот: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=column%20layout%20component:Blink%3ELayout%3EMultiCol&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Насчет поддержки все не так страшно. Там не поддерживаются лишь достаточно специфичные свойства `break-before, break-after, break-inside`. Спасибо, никогда не открывал эту вкладку на caniuse..

Comment: В общем я посмотрел в Ie, edge, ff, chrome обычной/canary и opera. На blink браузерах не работает, на остальных ок. Видимо только курить трекер и молиться что есть костыль.

Comment: Да уж. Пока придется обойтись без выкрутасов с этой фичей